# Get a list of user's downloaded app on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, permissions, user-permissions

Can ios apps get a data on which applications users have downloaded to their device similar to what [android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int)) allows?

Answer (score 5):

No this is not possible in iOS. iOS is focused on user privacy and security and giving developers information about which apps have been downloaded raises major privacy concerns.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible from code within the app. User information is kept private on purpose.

What you can do if your app is published is login to iTunes connect with your developer account and see data on your app for sessions, installs, and crashes.

I don't recommend this, but you could look into CNContacts or Address Book to see users data by getting their vCard and saving it as some analytics system. This will most likely cause you to get rejected unless you're very clear on what you're doing in the app.